# How to include a graphql schema file into an AWS Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

I am creating a simple AWS Cloudformation template file for an AppSync API. I would like to create the GraphQL schema in a separate file and reference it from the stack template but have been unable to do so.

The stack template is in a file `template.yaml`. The following snippet defines the GraphQL schema:

```
  GraphQLSchema:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema
    Properties: 
      ApiId: !GetAtt AppSyncAPI.ApiId
      DefinitionS3Location: schema.graphql
```

The GraphQL schema is in the same directory called in a separate file called `schema.graphql`.

```
schema {}
```

When in use the aws-cli to create the stack, the following error message appears in the Cloudformation events log when creating the GraphQLSchema:

"S3 location not valid for DefinitionS3Location"

How do I reference a local file for the schema and have the aws-cli automatically bundle it together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`aws cloudformation create-stack`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) will not work with a locally referenced schema.

First, package the files with [`aws cloudformation package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) which uploads the schema to the designated S3 bucket and replaces the local reference with the S3 bucket reference in the generated package. Then that package can be deployed using [`aws cloudformation deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There are only two options:

1. Create a script to upload your GraphQL schema to S3 automatically and reference at `DefinitionS3Location` or
2. create your GraphQL schema directly in your CloudFormation template:

```
AppSyncGraphQLSchema:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema
    DependsOn: AppSyncGraphQLApi
    Properties:
      ApiId: !GetAtt AppSyncGraphQLApi.ApiId
      Definition: |
        ...
        schema {
          query: Query
          mutation: Mutation
        }
        ...
```